# Google App Engine e-mail and attachment extensions

Tags: google-app-engine, email

In Google App Engine for python can I send e-mails with attachments that have no extension? What are the allowed extensions? Can I send zip files as attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot send attachments with no extension. Last time I checked (SDK 1.6.3) all the extensions are allowed except the ones blacklisted in

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
mail.EXTENSION_BLACKLIST
```

I have also found out in practice that .zip files are not allowed although .zip is not in that list as of 1.6.3.

This was first answered [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-python/emfJkCuAzu4).

Comment: You can send zip files, as long as they don't contain any of the blacklisted file types.  They also cannot contain zips.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html#Attachments

Comment: Dan, I just zipped a *.docx file and attempted to send it. I got the error (InvalidAttachmentTypeError:Invalid attachment type)

 File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 897, in send
    raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
InvalidAttachmentTypeError: Invalid attachment type

Comment: gae123, you have bested me with actual facts. I can't get this to work either. I'll look into it.

Comment: I followed up on this and confirmed that .zip attachments are not currently allowed.  The docs are incorrect.  Furthermore, the dev server incorrectly allows them, so you don't catch this until you're live.  I've filed bugs to get the docs and SDK corrected in the short term.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I am glad this post ended up being useful to the community. Please share the tickets---if they are public---to star them.